# Excel Formula - Create Account Number

Tags: excel

This to me seams very hard so kudos to anybody that can help. I am using the following formula to get the result i need.

```
=SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(UPPER(SUBSTITUTE(D30," ","")),3),"&","A")&"001"
```

This takes the Company name and gives me sort of what i need.

```
Barajas & Bustamante Archl
```

Result

```
BAR001
```

Which is great ! However due to the amount of customers, I receive the following issue.

```
BAR001  Barajas & Bustamante Archl
BAR001  Barnett Industries Inc
BAR001  Barnett Travel
BAR001  Barker Electronics
```

What i need is each account number to be unique like so

```
BAR001  Barajas & Bustamante Archl
BAR002  Barnett Industries Inc
BAR003  Barnett Travel
BAR004  Barker Electronics
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It would me much simpler if you use a separate column to get the first 3 letters. Would a solution using that be ok? You can always delete that column when you are done (you will need it again if the list grows though).

Comment: This would be fine as i will later import the data elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, let's say that the company names are in column D (starting on D2 and D1 has the column label). In Column B, you want to get some kind of ID and in column C, you will put the first 3 letters of the company name.

While trying to keep as much as possible as it is, you will use this in column C to get the first 3 letters:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(UPPER(SUBSTITUTE(D2," ","")),3),"&","A")
```

Then in column B, you will use this to get the ID:

```
=C2&TEXT(COUNTIF($C$2:C2,C2),"000")
```

This will count the number of times the first 3 letters appear in column C, from the beginning to the row on which the formula is put. In C2, it will look in C2:C2. In C3, the formula will look in C2:C3, etc. `TEXT` then formats this number to add the leading zeroes.

Finally, the part at the start will combine the first 3 letters with the count.

Comment: Thankyou so much, Saved me a massive headache.

Comment: @MattLeyland The pleasure is mine :)